# Django form eager load related objects before render template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a performance issue while rendering the template, because when I'm rendering N forms, for each form it loads a related object through the foreign key with a query.

**This is my situation**

I have a Statistic Model that belongs to a Player Model (1 to many). In the change_view template, I render N statistic forms and for each form, also the related Player (first name, last name).

**Here is the simple statistic form**

```
class StatisticForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = Statistic
```

How can I eager load Player with statistic form?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a [`ModelFormSet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets), as you said: "I render N statistic forms..." and fetch the related objects at once:

> > > formset = StatisticFormSet(queryset=Statistic.objects.select_related('player').all())

Note the key here is not the formset itself, but the usage of .select_related('player') on queryset creation. The ModelFormSet usage is just a suggestion for handling all those forms easier.

Hope that helps.